# How to get list of all inherited users in GCP Bigquery table from API call?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-iam

I'm trying to fetch a list of all inherited users who has access to a specific table in a big query. Please suggest an API call or URL which I can use to fetch the details.

Tried the below curl command:

```
curl -H "content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)" https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/my-project/datasets/my-dataset/tables/my-table:getIampolicy  -d {'options':{}}
```

With the above command I only got the bindings which are non-inherited.

Comment: Can you try using the command `gcloud asset search-all-resources --asset-types='bigquery.googleapis.com/Table' --project=project-id` or `gcloud asset analyze-iam-policy --organization=organization-id --full-resource-name=//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/project-id/datasets/dataset-id` to list the inherited users who has access to the table or dataset. Let me know if it’s helpful?

Comment: Hi @SudhirMaurya, Did the above comment help you in resolving the isssue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below commands to list the inherited users who have access to the dataset or table.

`gcloud asset search-all-iam-policies --scope=projects/project-id --query='resource://bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/project-id/datasets/dataset-id'`

`gcloud asset analyze-iam-policy --project=project-id --full-resource-name=//bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/project-id/datasets/dataset-id`

`gcloud asset search-all-resources --asset-types='bigquery.googleapis.com/Table' --project=project-id`

`'bigquery.googleapis.com/Table'`, this will show there is a table

Bigquery table and dataset are supported asset type in [Cloud Asset](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/supported-asset-types#searchable_asset_types).

For more information you can refer these documents

[1] https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/full-resource-names

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/asset/analyze-iam-policy

[3] https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/asset/search-all-iam-policies